# Каким образом можно связать python и php через stdin?

Tags: php, python, bash

У меня есть некий скрипт на python, который служит лаунчером для запуска фриды (https://frida.re/docs/functions/). Возможно ли передать его stdout в php скрипт?

```bsh
python3 loader.py | php reader.php
```

Проблема заключается в том, что необходимо использовать `sys.stdin.read()`, чтобы предотвратить выход из приложения.

```bsh
python3 -c 'print(1)' | xargs printf "data: %s"
#Выводит data: 1
```

А такой код не выводит ничего из-за блокировки stdin

```bsh
python3 -c 'import sys; print(1); sys.stdin.read();' | xargs printf "data: %s"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуй сбросить буфер stdout:

```
python3 -c $'import sys; import time; print("start"); \nwhile True: print("step") ; sys.stdout.flush() ; time.sleep(3)' | cat
```

Еще есть `python -u`.

P.S.

> использовать sys.stdin.read(), чтобы предотвратить выход из приложения.

ИМХО со скриптом явно что-то не то.

`while True: sleep(1000)`

`subprocess` [Смотреть на тему wait](https://pythonworld.ru/moduli/modul-subprocess.html)

Comment: Со скриптом все нормально. Вот пример из документации: https://frida.re/docs/functions/